# Iframe does not resize

Tags: html, css, iframe, media-queries

So i have this iframe

```
iframe {   
width: 39%;
height: 447px;
max-height: 447px;
}
```

I want it to become smaller on small devices so i added

```
@media only screen and (max-width:500px) { 
   iframe { 
   height: 150px !important; 
   max-height: 150px !important;
   } 
}
```

but it does not work, what is the reason for that?
greetings, 
herrsocke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:500px) { 
       iframe { 

       max-height: 150px !important;
       } 
        }
```